# wpf RadioButton Binding to different properties

Tags: wpf, boolean

I have the following SQL table structure

1. **DeleteOwn** as bit 0 or 1
2. **DeleteAll** as bit 0 or 1
3. **NoDelete** as Bit 0 or 1

In XAML I have the following

> ```
>                             <RadioButton  IsChecked="{Binding CurrentItem.Item[DeleteOwn]}" Content="Delete Own" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
>                             <RadioButton  IsChecked="{Binding CurrentItem.Item[DeleteAll]}" Content="Delete All" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,67,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
>                             <RadioButton  IsChecked="{Binding CurrentItem.Item[NoDelete]}" Content="No Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
> ```

Here is my code how I retrieve the data:

```
Property MyItems As BindingListCollectionView
Property CurrentItem As DataRowView
Sub LoadData()
    MyItems = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(GlobalApp.GetData("select * from mytable").DefaultView)
    NotifyProperty("MyItems")
End Sub
```

and here is how currentItem is associated

```
Private Sub ChangeSelected(sender As Object, e As RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs(Of Object))
           Dim MyTreeView As TreeView = DirectCast(sender, TreeView)
           CurrentItem = MyTreeView.SelectedItem
           NotifyProperty("CurrentItem")
End Sub
```

when the data loaded in to the window the values are show correct but after the values changed by clicking the radio buttons then the bindings are lost and it shows incorrect values to the radio buttons. 
How can I make it work?

Comment: post the code that holds `CurrentItem.Item[ ... `

Comment: I have update my question with sample code, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Don't know if that helps anybody else, but I was able to fix it by doing 2 things.

- In Every Radio button I was have to declare 3 different group names(which for me this is wrong but to make it work I didn't have other way), for example

  ```
                      <RadioButton GroupName="a"/>
                      <RadioButton GroupName="b"/>
                      <RadioButton GroupName="c"/>
  ```
- Every time one of the radio buttons change a status to True the other radio buttons should be set to false ,I was expecting this behavior to be out of the box

  (when you have bindings in the radio buttons is not working)

but I was have to implement it by my self since the bindings were not work properly ,so in code behind I put a logic when one of my properties change to True the other properties are set to False